# What is the optimal race choice for maximum melee damage for my pure Hexblade build?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, damage, melee-combat, hexblade

Stat rolls 18, 14, 16, 8, 10, 12

Pure Hexblade build, no multiclass. We start at level 4, probably play to level 10 at most.

I have two choices:

One a classic Vuman with PAM, GWM + 18 CHA on level 4, attacking with advantage with +3 (+8 - 5 from GWM) with Pact Glaive +1. From level 5 I have 3 attacks with GWM and on level 8- +2 CHA for 20 CHA and I am done.

Other one is Half-Elf drow with GWM (and later Elven Accuracy) and 20 CHA on level 4, attacking with advantage with +4 (+9 - 5 from GWM). However to get Elven Accuracy I have to wait till level 8 so max I will attack till level 8 is 2 attacks with advantage. From level 8 I will have two attacks with super advantage but Vuman will have 3 attacks with 20 CHA on level 8.

Darkness on Half-Elf is nice but both will switch to using Shadow of Moil anyway.

Since game is till level 10, I think Vuman is better choice as he comes online faster and allows to have 3 attacks from level 4. Even if we see level 12- he would still come ahead as he could take Resilence (CON) and have concentration effects much longer vs half-elf who would pick PAM on level 12.

I like Half-Elf Elven Accuracy, however I think that PAM is just too good to skip on pure Hexblade.

The Goal is maximum melee power (DPR) abusing advantage from Darkness/Shadow of Moil/Greater Invisibility etc to offset GWM. I just want to get on enemies faces and kill them with my Pact Weapon Glaive/Greatsword.

Comment: What are your goals for the character? What do you want to optimise about it? Without this information there is no way we can address your issue and the question will likely be put on hold.

Comment: Um, maximum melee power abusing advantage from Darkness/Shadow of Moil/Greater Invisibility etc. 

I just want to get on enemies faces and kill them with Pact Weapon.

Comment: "melee power" meaning damage?

Comment: Yes, dmg or DPR if you prefer. No multiclass

Comment: No problem- so what do you think?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 5):

### Roll/Hit-wise, it's about a wash. Go human.

You don't really need to keep your bonus action open for anything, so burning it on a weapon butt attack through PAM isn't really a cost.

You're either rolling 2x on 3 attacks or 3x on 2 attacks. The hit rate for Elven Accuracy (EA) means, statistically, you're going to be hitting roughly 25% to 50% more often against a given AC ([per any dice](https://anydice.com/program/145dc)) so the net hits will probably end up about the same.

Half Elf Drow gives you Darkness, but you can pick that up as a Warlock anyway. As a damage-focused character, what else are you going to spend your spell slots on?

Human gets 3 attacks at level 3 but Half Elf wouldn't get EA until level 8, so go Human to be more dangerous sooner.

Comment: I plan to just use spell to give myself advantage (Darkness, Shadow of Moil) and Eldricht Smite later when I crit (if enemy is worth Smite) or Armor of Agathys/Blink to boost myself more before combat starts. I don't plan anything else, just focus on melee with everything.

Comment: @ben Right, sorry, that's my point. Your options for spellcasting are very limited so your spell slots aren't going to be used for much other than Darkness/SoM. Saving one a day because of Drow magic doesn't really give you much since Warlock slots refresh after a short rest. So the advantages of a human outweigh the benefits of a half elf.

Comment: 3x 2 attack rolls are superior to 2x 3. If you hit with all rolls (not that rare), you will do 50% more damage.

Comment: It may just be me, but Extra Attack and Elven Accuracy can both be abbreviated to EA, which caused a bit of confusion when talking about number of attacks.